# Why I get 'avoid using JavaScript unary operator as property name' in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a vue.js template, I have this code to delete a joke

```
<div  v-on:click="delete(joke)" class="btn btn-sm">delete</div>
```

and the method to do so:

```
delete: function(joke) {
    console.log('delete requested');
    axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/delete" , {
        id: joke.id,
        token: this.token,
    }).then( (res) => { 
        this.$router.push({ path: '/' });
    })
    .catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error);             
  });
},
```

I get this error:

> avoid using JavaScript unary operator as property name: "delete(joke)"
>   in expression v-on:click="delete(joke)"

The odd thing is that, in other components, I pass the same `joke` object to methods in the same manner and get no errors.

I'm wondering what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: It's complaining about the name "delete". That's a keyword in JavaScript. It will work as a property name however so I don't know what's complaining about it or why.

Comment: @Pointy The "what" is [Vue's compiler](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/43485fbc5b779e02122c3b7fc64296a2cfee31f6/src/compiler/error-detector.js) (see the `checkEvent` function). As for the "why": that has to do with how Vue binds the scope of the inline expression. It's standard to pass a method name, like in the example. But you can also pass an anonymous function inline (like `v-on:click="() => delete(joke)"`), which Vue needs to prevent from happening.

Comment: @thanksd ah I see. OK that makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> I'm wondering what is wrong here

`delete` is an *operator* defined in JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

> and how to fix it?

Choose a different method name than `delete` ...

Comment: But it still works as an object property name; property names can be *any* string value.

Comment: @Pointy yes, but the message was referring to the `v-on:click="delete(joke)"` part. Bhojendra went into a little more detail in their answer as to why that's a different issue.

Comment: sadly it still complains even if it is clearly used as a property. e.g. "ctrl.delete()" I think the check could be a little more sophisticated

Answer (score 2):

You can name whatever you want as your property name in an object. But binding in a `v-on:` requires to be an expression. Using `delete` keyword there supposed be uncompleted expression. If you choose other than the reserved keyword, then you get the method that you have defined in your vue instance.

I can see the following error on visual code IDE:

> [vue-language-server] 'v-on' directives require that attribute value or verb modifiers.
>
> [vue-language-server] Parsing error: Unexpected end of expression.

Thus to resolve the problem you must give a different name which is not reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

delete is a javascript reserve word its use to delete an object property. so change method name.